# Get selected item from a bound listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

i have a listbox of users and i want to get the selected item from it.I used selecteditem but it returns always zero .
This is my listbox xaml code:

```
 <ListBox  Name="_imageList" Margin="10,10,10,0"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="250" BorderThickness="0" SelectionChanged="List_clicked">
        <!--<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown"  Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>-->
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="Enfant">
                <Border CornerRadius="30">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="80" Click="btn_click">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding avatar}"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="nom" Text="{Binding prenom}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
 private void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnKidClick != null)
        {
            kid = new Enfant();
            OnKidClick(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
            var item = _imageList.SelectedItem;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I understand it, the previous [`answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580282/how-do-i-make-a-clickable-listbox) of @RohitVats helped you. Maybe you should accept it?

Comment: yes it helped , and i'm not working with MVVM ,I didn't find a well structured tutorial that could help me

Comment: You are using `Button` what he advised you: `Use Button in place of Image and override template of Button to give it an Image look, so that you can have clickable image.`, MVVM nothing to do with.

Answer (score 0):

You already handle the selected item in the `SelectionChanged="List_clicked"` method do what you need to do in that method.

Comment: yes i i did, but it always returns the first item in the list not the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ICollectionView for ListBox source and you can get easily selected item using CurrentItem property.

```
 public class UserInfoViewModel 
  {
    private ICollectionView _employeeCollectionView;
    public ICollectionView EmployeeCollectionView
    {
        get
        {
            return _employeeCollectionView;
        }
        private set { _employeeCollectionView = value; }
    }
  private void GetEmployee()
    {
     EmployeeCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(HERE-IS-YOUR-COLLECTION);

     EmployeeCollectionView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(_customerView_CurrentChanged);
   }

 void _customerView_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var selectedEmployee= EmployeeCollectionView.CurrentItem as Employee;
    }
}
```

bind ListBox to your collection.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollectionView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,     NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">


</ListBox >
```

hope this help.

Comment: would you please explain further how can i bind my listbox to ICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

I would do it MVVM style.  Then in your ListBox, set the property

```
SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedEmployee}"
```

Then create a SelectedEmployee property in whichever ViewModel is providing the data for your ListBox (the DataContext for this View).  The setter of your property will always be called when the selected item gets changed.

I posted some code similar to this, demonstrating how to hook up views and viewmodels with bindings, over here:

[Hiding A Listbox Item in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524070/hiding-a-listbox-item-in-wpf/22543143#22543143)